# How do I select a build in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Normally there is a "+" button but I don't see one right now because Apple have updated iTunes Connect and introduced a bug. How can I get around this bug and select a build to submit my app to the App Store.

[image]

Comment: This is a valid question, just awkwardly worded. It seems to take a bit of time to be able to add the build. Maybe wait until you get the email, then hit refresh a few times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just submitted some updates an hour ago. There is no bug. After you submit your binary through Xcode or Application Loader, nothing will appear in iTunes Connect until you get an email from Apple telling you that the submission has been processed. Then you can go into iTunes Connect and see the circled + icon next to "Build".

The processing time can be anywhere from a few minutes to days.

It has been this way for several months now.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer. This issue will show up when a build has been processed (email confirmation received) and even tested through TestFlight.

Comment: I have received the email stating `build has completed processing`, yet I cant see + button beside build button

Comment: Did you see it processing under the TestFlight tab? I could conceive of accidentally submitting to the wrong account. Also, does the version number match (given that leading zeros in each integer of the version get stripped?).

Comment: You can also upload a new build number- sometimes the next build gets processed much more quickly.